# Can Spring Boot read config from a json containing arrays of objects?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to reproduce [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-json-properties) so I can load configs from a json file within the app's folder. But there appears to be some issue with the binding to the properties class. When I inspect the nested config I don't see the arrays of objects I'd expect, but an array of LinkedHashMaps.

Any ideas to accomplish this?

**Debugging:**

[image]

**DemoBotApplication.java:**

```java
package com.myapp.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {JsonProperties.class})
public class DemoBotApplication {

    @Autowired
    private TestService test;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoBotApplication.class).initializers(new JsonPropertyContextInitializer()).run();
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        test.test();
    }
}
```

**TestService.java:**

```java
@Service
public class TestService {
    
    @Autowired
    private BotConfig botConfig;
    
    public void test() {
        List<com.myapp.demo.config.BotConfig.Device> devices = botConfig.getDevices();
    }
}
```

**JsonProperties.java:**

```java
package com.myapp.demo.config;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "json")
@Data
public class JsonProperties {

    private String serverUrl;
    private List<Device> devices;

    @Data
    public static class Device {

        private int id;
        private int period;
        private float step;
        private List<Waypoint> waypoints;

        @Data
        public static class Waypoint {

            private double latitude;
            private double longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

**JsonPropertyContextInitializer.java:**

```java
package com.myapp.demo.config;

public class JsonPropertyContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private final static String JSON_PREFIX = "json";

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        try {
            Resource resource = configurableApplicationContext.getResource("file:./config.json");
            Map readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Map.class);
            Set<Map.Entry> set = readValue.entrySet();
            List<MapPropertySource> propertySources = convertEntrySet(set, Optional.empty());
            for (PropertySource propertySource : propertySources) {
                configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static List<MapPropertySource> convertEntrySet(Set<Map.Entry> entrySet, Optional<String> parentKey) {
        return entrySet.stream().map((Map.Entry e) -> convertToPropertySourceList(e, parentKey))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<MapPropertySource> convertToPropertySourceList(Map.Entry entry, Optional<String> parentKey) {
        String key = parentKey.map(s -> s + ".").orElse("") + (String) entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        return convertToPropertySourceList(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static List<MapPropertySource> convertToPropertySourceList(String key, Object value) {
        // handles arrays
        if (value instanceof ArrayList) {
            ArrayList list = (ArrayList) value;

            List<MapPropertySource> converted = new ArrayList<MapPropertySource>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                LinkedHashMap map = (LinkedHashMap) list.get(i);
                Set<Map.Entry> entrySet = map.entrySet();
                String arrayKey = String.format("%s[%d]", key, i);
                converted.addAll(convertEntrySet(entrySet, Optional.ofNullable(arrayKey)));
            }

            return converted;
        }

        // handles nested objects
        if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            LinkedHashMap map = (LinkedHashMap) value;
            Set<Map.Entry> entrySet = map.entrySet();
            return convertEntrySet(entrySet, Optional.ofNullable(key));
        }

        String finalKey = String.format("%s.%s", JSON_PREFIX, key);

        return Collections.singletonList(new MapPropertySource(finalKey, Collections.singletonMap(finalKey, value)));
    }
}
```

**config.json:**

```json
{
  "serverUrl": "localhost:5093",
  "devices": [
    {
      "id": "123456789",
      "period": 5,
      "step": 0.001,
      "speed": 40,
      "waypoints": [
        {
          "latitude": 48.8537,
          "longitude": 2.344347
        },
        {
          "latitude": 48.855235,
          "longitude": 2.345852
        },
        {
          "latitude": 48.857238,
          "longitude": 2.347153
        },
        {
          "latitude": 48.858509,
          "longitude": 2.342563
        },
        {
          "latitude": 48.856066,
          "longitude": 2.340432
        },
        {
          "latitude": 48.85478,
          "longitude": 2.34223
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```